# Magic Methods __Call doesn't work well with multiple arguments

Tags: php, magic-methods

I have a problem with magic method `__call`

The following code works well, except when there is more than one argument in the call of method.  I've tried different solutions without any good result (just `$args` or `implode(', ' $args)` doesn't work)

```
public function __call($method, $args) {
    if($this->methods[$method] != NULL)
            return $this->objects[$this->methods[$method]]->$method($args[0]);
    else    trigger_error("Call undefined method " . $this->class . "::" . $method, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

That works too if I write it like this:

```
return $this->objects[$this->methods[$method]]->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[3]);
```

But as you can see this isn't correct because a function can have 0 to infinite arguments.

Do you know how fix the script for multiple arguments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return call_user_func_array($this->objects[$this->methods[$method]]->$method, $args);
```

See http://php.net/call_user_func_array.

Comment: thankyou for help

      return call_user_func_array(array($this->objects[$this->methods[$method]], $method), $args);

 works well :D

return call_user_func_array($this->objects[$this->methods[$method]]->$method, $args);
 dosen't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters){

    if (in_array($method, ['get', 'post'])) {
        return $this->$method(...$parameters);
    }
}
```